# Unity IoC and Solrnet

Tags: unity-container, solrnet

I just started using Solrnet in my application only to discover that using the default settings it decides all by itself to replace my IoC container with its own (common service locator), which seems to me to be quite unexpected and "arrogant" of it.

I'm using Unity and the common service locator and I'd like to continue using them if possible.
It seems kind of silly that I have to change something so unrelated in order to use Solrnet which otherwise seems to be well written software.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SolrNet is setup to support Unity. However, you need to do a little setup to get it working with Unity. Please refer to the [RegistryTests.cs](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Unity.SolrNetIntegration.Tests/RegistryTests.cs) file from the SolrNet source unit tests for examples of how to setup SolrNet with Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just starting to investigate that, kind of worried that I'm going to have to pull the source and call this directly though. I like being able to use nuget.

Comment: I have the nuget dll installed, any way I can avoid having to pull the source code and build a dll myself?

Comment: You should not need to pull and build the dll. The latest version 0.4.0 Beta 2 (which is highly stable) is available on the projects Google Code site - http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/downloads/list

Comment: Forgot to add, after you pull the latest dll version, just copy it to your SolrNet packages folder (overwriting the one that is already there) and you won't need to change your project references and will still be reliant upon nuget.

Comment: So apparently that is version 0.4 where as the nuget version is 0.3

Comment: Yes, v0.3.1 is the current release. Once v0.4 comes out of Beta the author will update the NuGet feed. You need to get a version newer than v0.3.1, as the Unity Integration was not added until after v0.3.1